# Dashboard Dashlets Unauthorized

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 4.4
CiviCRM 4.6.10

I installed recently and was in initial setup stages. I had dashlets working fine and created new dashlets. Now all dashlets are giving error

401 - Unauthorized
Your authorization failed.
Please try refreshing the page and fill in the correct login details.

I was working with extensions and configuring the URLs for extension folders. I installed CiviRules and logger successfully. I've dsiabled these and removed extension URLS now.

I've searched and cannot find similar errors.No Wordpress errors showing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 2):

Resolved....Htaccess password protection on site prevented dashlets showing